# Are differences of open balls open?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

In the metric topology the open sets of a metric space $X$ are union of open balls, but if $r>r'$ then $\forall x_0 \in X$

$B(x_0, r) = B(x_0, r') \cup(B(x_0, r) - B(x_0, r'))$

is open, that in turn means that $B(x_0, r) - B(x_0, r')$ is open.

And that is not an open ball, so why is it open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An open set can be written as a union of an open set and a non-open set. For example, $(0, 2) = (0, 1) \cup [1, 2)$.

So your argument after "in turn" is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

By no means does that imply that $B(x_0,r)\setminus B(x_0,r')$ is open: see for instance $X=\Bbb R$, $x_0=0$, $r'=1/2$ and $r=1$. $(-1,-1/2]\cup[1/2,1)$ isn't open.